# Setting up GitHub runner on AIX server with IBM Power hardware (PowerPC)

Tags: github, server, aix, powerpc, runner

I'm trying to set up a GitHub runner on an AIX server that's running on IBM Power hardware (PowerPC). I've been following the steps for setting up the runner on Linux, but I'm not sure if it's possible to run Linux commands on this hardware.

The client has told us that it's not possible, but we're not sure if there are any workarounds or alternatives. Has anyone had experience setting up a GitHub runner on AIX with IBM Power hardware? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Our team is still in the research phase on how to start this. Client is not allowing us to try out linux based commands on PowerPC machines as that wont anyways work.

Comment: It seems to require some `dotnet for linux` component which might not exist on Aix. https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/main/docs/start/envlinux.md